# Next.Js-having issues in formatting markdown

Tags: next.js, frontend, markdown

```
export async function getPostData(id: string) {
  const fullPath = path.join(postsDirectory, `${id}.md`);
  const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, "utf8");

  const matterResult = matter(fileContents);

  const processedContent = await remark()
    .use(html)
    .process(matterResult.content);

  const contentHtml = processedContent.toString();

  const blogPostWithHTML: BlogPost & { contentHtml: string } = {
    id,
    title: matterResult.data.title,
    date: matterResult.data.date,
    contentHtml,
  };

  return blogPostWithHTML;
}
```

It is my code but here, .use(html) doesn't work
[I have got a picture to show my error symbol(red underline)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPJ78.png)
Actually, it is sample code snippet work perfectly in other example project though mine doesn't work.
What is the reason? And what shall do to solve this bug!

I followed YouTube tutorial and it is almost same to there. I really can't find the reason. I can't understand why red underline that stands for error appeared in my `.use(html)`

Comment: Add more information like the error you get and the full code, where you import `html`